# Is there a walk around for 1000 char limit set for defining table structure while creating a source end point for S3 in AWS Data migration Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-migration, aws-dms

I want to create an end point for s3 bucket in aws dms for migrating data from s3 to redshift. When defining table structure in JSON format, I am getting an error that character limit is set to 1000 characters. Is there a walk around for this or am I doing something wrong?
Json template shared on aws dms website also has more then 1000 characters. I am thinking how to have a walk around if table structure has more then 20 columns.

Also, if some one has created a dms task for sql server to s3 to redshift. I want to understand how update files which gets created in s3 bucket when you enable replication are loaded to redshift as an updated rather then new table or row.

Thank you in advance.

I tried removing space and `eol` characters

```
{
    "TableCount": "1",
    "Tables": [
        {
            "TableName": "employee",
            "TablePath": "hr/employee/",
            "TableOwner": "hr",
            "TableColumns": [
                {
                    "ColumnName": "Id",
                    "ColumnType": "INT8",
                    "ColumnNullable": "false",
                    "ColumnIsPk": "true"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "LastName",
                    "ColumnType": "STRING",
                    "ColumnLength": "20"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "FirstName",
                    "ColumnType": "STRING",
                    "ColumnLength": "30"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "HireDate",
                    "ColumnType": "DATETIME"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "OfficeLocation",
                    "ColumnType": "STRING",
                    "ColumnLength": "20"
                }
            ],
            "TableColumnsTotal": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

Error : Must be no longer than 1000 characters

Answer (score 0):

On a unix system (EC2,..) use `tr -s " "`. When your data has tabs, first use `expand -1`.

```
echo '{
    "TableCount": "1",
    "Tables": [
        {
            "TableName": "employee",
            "TablePath": "hr/employee/",
            "TableOwner": "hr",
            "TableColumns": [
                {
                    "ColumnName": "Id",
                    "ColumnType": "INT8",
                    "ColumnNullable": "false",
                    "ColumnIsPk": "true"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "LastName",
                    "ColumnType": "STRING",
                    "ColumnLength": "20"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "FirstName",
                    "ColumnType": "STRING",
                    "ColumnLength": "30"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "HireDate",
                    "ColumnType": "DATETIME"
                },
                {
                    "ColumnName": "OfficeLocation",
                    "ColumnType": "STRING",
                    "ColumnLength": "20"
                }
            ],
            "TableColumnsTotal": "5"
        }
    ]
}' | tr -s " "
```

Comment: I have already tried removing the spaces, tabs etc. I am looking for solution around the limit set by aws. Or a way to use s3 as source for moving data to redshift using AWS DMS. I am not thinking if I should focus on using copy command and try to figure out a way to join data generated by DMS in Replication mode

Comment: When I try the above command and pipe it through `| wc`, it returns 582 characters.

Comment: Thank you yes you solution works for small table, but I am looking for something which has maybe 50 column, in that case the limit is bit difficult to pass by. I tried removing tabs and spaces and make it work for small table but I am thinking about generalization for a schema.